WP Как отфильтровать списки виджетов от аргументов class?
Имеется стандартный вывод элементов Виджета - Последние посты. Как сделать так, что б к тегу <ul> не добавлялись значения class по умолчанию ?

Мой хук-фильтр не срабатывает.
<?php
add_filter('widget_posts_args', 'remove_latest_posts_classes');
function remove_latest_posts_classes($args) {
    $args['before_widget'] = str_replace('class="wp-block-latest-posts__list wp-block-latest-posts"', '', $args['before_widget']);
    return $args;
}


Интересно чем классы могли помешать? Что заставляет понапрасну растрачивать ресурсы (как человеческие, так и технические), занимаясь не просто бессмысленными, но и в какой-то мере вредным действиями?

Верю, согласен, но задачи клиента не обсуждаються.  Решение через СSS не подошло как альтернатива.

Можно использовать хук widget_block_content - позволяет изменять контент прямо перед выводом. Т.е. буквально уже собранный виджет в виде текста отредактировать, убирая из него нежелательные классы. Очень грубый и топорный метод, но рабочий. Посмотреть о фильтре можно на wp-kama
add_filter( 'widget_block_content', 'wp_kama_widget_block_content_filter', 10, 3 );
function wp_kama_widget_block_content_filter( $content, $instance, $widget ){
    $content = str_replace('class="wp-block-latest-posts__list wp-block-latest-posts"', '', $content);
    return $content;
}

